# Subtracting dates returns float

Tags: php, date

I have a function that calculates the number of days left for a product listing to expire.When i run the code below I am getting floating point numbers e.g 3.4722222222222E-5

```
$days_left = date('d', strtotime($this->expiry_date) - strtotime($date)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
$this->days_left = $days_left;
```

When I round of the result

```
 (round)$this->days_left
```

a keep getting 0

Comment: try `round($this->days_left);` not `(round)$this->days_left` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php))

Comment: are you sure that $this->expiry_date is having the value all the times, check whether the value is comming when you get that kind of float result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime($this->expiry_date) - strtotime($date)` gives you the time difference in seconds.

`date('d', $time)` would give you the day part of that `$time`, removing any month/year part. And you divide number of seconds per day in that figure which is already a day number?? Floating point would result, obviously, as computers just blindly do the division.

Instead, ditch the `date` function to get number of days, but divide your time (in seconds) with number of seconds in a day:

```
$days_left = (strtotime($this->expiry_date) - strtotime($date)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

And you don't "type cast" to `round` which doesn't exist. As per comments, do `round($this->days_left)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do calculations with dates correctly, you should use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. The difference between dates (duration of something) should then be rendered as a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, which gives exact differences.